# Is there a word describing a functionally obsolete design choice?

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a word that would describe something like a modern phone that retains a rotary dial.  The dial's design was originally functional, but phone's function doesn't rely on the dial any more - it's just an aesthetic choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. [Skeuomorph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph).

**skeuomorph** /ˈskjuːəmɔrf/ n. a derivative object that retains ornamental design cues from structures that were necessary in the original.